# Props are undefined in redux component

Tags: redux, react-redux

Given the following component, which is structually similar to [redux's demo component](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#containersaddtodojs).
My primary issue is that props is **always undefined** even if the state in the store is perfectly valid

Note: In the link I'm looking at the **'containers/AddTodo.js'**, if the link doesn't directly take you to the snippet

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Glyphicon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Glyphicon';
import Label from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Label';


let HeaderContainer = ({props}) => { //props = undefined
  return(
    <div>

      <Label bsStyles="warning">
        <Glyphicon glyph="exclamation" />
      {props.openCount}
      </Label>

      <Label bsStyle="success">
        <Glyphicon glyph="ok" />
      {props.completedCount}
      </Label>

    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    openCount: state.tasks.filter( task => !task.completed).length,
    completedCount: state.tasks.filter( task => task.completed ).length
  };
}

HeaderContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderContainer);
export default HeaderContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{}` from the `({props})`. If you want to use destructuring, try `({openCount, completedCount})`

```
let HeaderContainer = (props) => //...

let HeaderContainer = ({openCount, completedCount}) => //..
```